# javascript calculator input background

Tags: javascript, calculator

Hi just out of educational purpose im trying to do a few things with my calculator i did, im trying to get the display to change color depending on result, this is the closest i've come, but it just shows red no matter what the result is, so what more do i need to add?

```
 <script>
 function checkNum() {
 var x = document.kalk.disp.value; 
 if (x.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)) { 
     kalk.disp.value=("Endast siffror!"); 
    kalk.disp.style.background = "red"; 
 }   else {
    kalk.disp.value = eval(x);
   (eval.value===0)
    kalk.disp.style.background = "green";
   (eval.value>=1)
    kalk.disp.style.background = "blue";
  (eval.value<=-1)
    kalk.disp.style.background = "red";
}
}
</script>
```

here's the html

```
 <form name="kalk"> 
 <input type="text" name="disp" >
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="7" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='7'">
 <input type="button" value="8" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='8'">
 <input type="button" value="9" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='9'">
 <input type="button" value="*" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='*'">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="4" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='4'">
 <input type="button" value="5" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='5'">
 <input type="button" value="6" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='6'">
 <input type="button" value="-" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='-'">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="1" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='1'">
 <input type="button" value="2" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='2'">
 <input type="button" value="3" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='3'">
 <input type="button" value="+" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='+'">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="C" OnClick="kalk.disp.value=''">
 <input type="button" value="0" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='0'">
 <input type="button" value="." OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='.'">
 <input type="button" value="=" OnClick="checkNum()" >
 </form>
```

its basically this that i have added

```
 (eval.value===0)
 kalk.disp.style.background = "green";
 (eval.value>=1)
 kalk.disp.style.background = "blue";
 (eval.value<=-1)
  kalk.disp.style.background = "red";
```

Comment: what is `document.kalk.disp.value` supposed to be?

Comment: Several things don't seem right here, but without the related html I can't give any meaningful suggestions.

Comment: @JaromandaX i have edited the post

Comment: get rid of `document.` from `document.kalk.disp.value` - why you incorrectly used `document.` the first time only is odd.

Comment: @ZivWeissman big thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the eval wrong.

You need some if-statements or something like this:

```
function checkNum() {
    var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
    if (x.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)) {
        kalk.disp.value = ("Endast siffror!");
        kalk.disp.style.background = "red";
    } else {
        var result = eval(x);

        kalk.disp.value = result;
        if (result > 0) {
            kalk.disp.style.background = "blue";
        } else if (result === 0) {
            kalk.disp.style.background = "green";
        } else {
            kalk.disp.style.background = "red";
        }

    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/oaj41ttx/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkNum() {
var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
if (x.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)) {
    kalk.disp.value = ("Endast siffror!");
    kalk.disp.style.background = "red";
} else {
    var result = eval(x);

    kalk.disp.value = result;
    if (result > 0) {
        kalk.disp.style.background = "blue";
    } else if (result === 0) {
        kalk.disp.style.background = "green";
    } else {
        kalk.disp.style.background = "red";
    }

}
```